# Converting update-rc.d redis_6379 defaults to chkconfig command

Tags: centos, services, init-script, chkconfig

I'm trying to run the command below on CentOS and of course I get command not found:

```
$ update-rc.d redis_6379 defaults
```

How do I then perform the equivalent using `chkconfig`?

Comment: update-rc.d doesn't not exist on Red Hat distros such as Fedora/CentOS/etc. The equivalent would be to use `chkconfig`, eg. `chkconfig redis_6379 on` or `chkconfig --level 345 redis_6379 on`.

Answer (score 2):

**final edit:**

ok for the sake of closure (and being helpful) i'm updating this post with some notes. although the commands in this posts original form 'work', they seem to be, from my naive understanding, deprecated.

so as pointed out by @jayhendren, the replacement commands are:

```
~$ [sudo] systemctl enable redis_6379
~$ [sudo] systemctl start redis_6379
```

now, this may work for you without any further steps BUT if you're running SELinux and aren't paying attention, prepare yourself for a session of frustration (at least, if you're like me and always forget SELinux has a say in everything you do...).

anyway, for me, prior to getting those two commands working i executed:

```
~$ sudo setenforce 0 // turn off selinux
...
/* run the two commands */
/* i also added (maybe unnecessary): */
...
~$ sudo systemctl reload-daemon // akin to chkconfig --add i think
...
~$ sudo setenforce 1 // don't forget to fire'er back up again

**optional: verify selinux is doin' its thang**

~$ sudo getenforce // should return 'Enforcing' if run after the last step
```

hope this tip saves a future me from an hours worth of trouble.

**ninja edit:**

forgot the word `on` in the example command

**original post:**

@jordanm states two commands are needed but i can only find one in his reply (i am known to miss the obvious though)... anyway, i'm not sure if it was necessary but i also ran this command:

```
~$ [sudo] chkconfig --add redis_6379
```

after that, i ran the command in @jordanm's reply:

```
~$ [sudo] chkconfig redis_6379 on
~$ [sudo] service redis_6379 start
```

and all appears to be working thus far (centOS 7) ...

Comment: Use `systemctl` on CentOS 7.x instead of `chkconfig` and `service`.  For instance: `systemctl enable redis_6379; systemctl start redis_6379`.

Comment: oh neat, i did not know that -- thanks for the tip!may i prod for further information and ask specifically: why use one over the other?

Comment: systemd replaced sysVinit in EL7. Scripts called `chkconfig` and `service` are still available for compatibility's sake, but they're now just wrappers for systemd commmands.

Comment: i see -- thanks, very informative for someone learning (like me)... a final request, if not too broad of a question, is there any online resource where i could read up on this specific topic further? not including wikipedia ...

Comment: https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/7/html/System_Administrators_Guide/

Comment: nice, thanks again (now only if only the site were mobile-first/responsive for easy reading on me phone.... /firstworldproblems).

Answer (score 1):

It is important to understand what the command does in order to use the equivalent on a different system. Here is the description of "defaults" in the update-rc.d manpage:

```
   If  defaults is used then update-rc.d will make links to start the ser
   vice in runlevels 2345 and to stop the service in  runlevels  016.
```

In order to replicate this in `chkconfig`, two commands are needed:

```
chkconfig redis_6379 on
```

By default, chkconfig assumes levels 2345. Any runlevels not specified as `on`, will be marked as `off`. This will be levels 016.